# Roslyn DiagnosticAnalyzer With Document Access

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've written a diagnostic analyzer to check if Const names have been created in a resx file in the solution and localize them to use the resx file.   I need to gain access to the Document/Solution my field declaration has been registered in

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeConstDeclaration, SyntaxKind.FieldDeclaration);    
} 

public static void AnalyzeConstDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var semantic = (FieldDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
}
```

I don't see a way to get the Document/Solution in the `AnalysisContext`
Nor do I see a way to get it from the SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext or the Semantic Model.

How can I get the Solution or Document in the Diagnostic Analyzer?

**Edit**

I tried getting the solution through the AdhocWorkspace however the current projects are not populated so that will not work.

```
var solution = new AdhocWorkspace().CurrentSolution;
```